# Executing stages of Jenkins pipeline in parallel on different slaves

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'm using a 6 slave - 4 executors each Jenkins setup to run my scripted multi-branch pipeline.

The issue I'm facing occurs when I try to execute the 4 stages of my pipeline in parallel on different **slaves** and not **executors**. As the Jenkins is shared between multiple teams I cannot limit the slave to one executor in order to ensure the 1 stage - 1 slave relation. I tried adding the `disableConcurrentBuilds()` option but still no luck.

How can I ensure that the 4 parallel stages are allocated to 4 different slaves?

Answer (score -1):

In a similar situation, we've limited the number of executors to 1. Where formerly the VMs were powerful enough to run 4 executors, we've destroyed them and created 4 small VMs instead, with 1 executor each. This guarantees parallel execution on different VMs.

The reason for that was, that — while you can make a reasonable effort to make sure your team's Stage A does not interfere with your team's Stage B (at this time it looks like they *do* interfere, hence your question) — you cannot make any assumptions about whether a) some of your stages won't break some other team's stages; or b) their stages will break yours. In our case, we ran out of disk space on stage, so let's cleanup docker images before, right? Oopsie — another executor is using the image, and the docker daemon is shared between all the executors. Here's another scenario: your stage creates a big file - storage is exhausted - up to *four* jobs fail (yours, as well as three innocent by-executers).

Your best course of action seems to be convincing the powers to replace big 4-executor machines with 4 small 1-executor machines.

Your other options include using the "lockable resource" plugin and locking e.g. the name of the machine. This won't prevent scheduling different parts of your pipeline on the same machine, but will hold one of the stages till the previous one has finished. In our experience, this leads to a great increase in the pipeline execution time versus no tangible benefit whatsoever.

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I need the slave machines to be 'powerful' enough to run my very exigent docker containers, so downgrading the slaves isn't a solution. I was also thinking of labeling each agent uniquely and mapping the stages one per dedicated agent, but this will leave 2 out of my 6 machines unused and will also make unusable the jenkins load balancing between slaves. Lockable resource is indeed the last solution.

Comment: As far as I know, the labels are per slave, you can't give a label to a specific executor. If you map each stage with a different label, two of your stages — e.g. from different branches — may end up running simultaneously on the same slave anyway.

Comment: you should force your parallel execution to run on different labels. then the number of executors per label does no matter.